# What is the alternative to deprecated the FileUtils.writeStringToFile method?

Tags: java

I need to write a content to file in a single statement something like  `FileUtils.writeStringToFile`.

Is there any alternative to it since it is deprecated?

Comment: Going by [the documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeStringToFile-java.io.File-java.lang.String-java.nio.charset.Charset-), the versions of `writeStringToFile` where you specify an encoding are not deprecated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By going through this [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeStringToFile(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)), It states that:

```
Deprecated. 2.5 use writeStringToFile(File, String, Charset) instead
Writes a String to a file creating the file if it does not exist using the default encoding for the VM.
```

You can follow this example:

```
final File file = new File(getTestDirectory(), "file_name.txt");
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, "content", "ISO-8859-1");
```

You can pass `(String) null` in your argument if you don't want to pass the encoding.

For more information, you can go through the link:
[Usage link](http://www.javadocexamples.com/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils/writeStringToFile(File%20file,String%20data,String%20encoding).html)

Answer (score 5):

Use this one

```
File file = ...
String data = ...

try{
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, data, Charset.defaultCharset());
}catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Files` from the Java standard library aswell - unless you need to use apache commons.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;

// to write to your file use

try {
    // To overwrite
    Files.write(Paths.get("Your\\path"), "YourString".getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
    // To append to the file
    Files.write(Paths.get("Your\\path"), "YourString".getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The fix is to add `Charset.defaultCharset()` as the 3rd argument.

E.g. change from

```java
writeStringToFile(file, data)
```

to

```java
writeStringToFile(file, data, Charset.defaultCharset())
```

Source:

The [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeStringToFile(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String)) says:

> Deprecated. 2.5 use writeStringToFile(File, String, Charset) instead

The [source code](https://github.com/apache/commons-io/blob/rel/commons-io-2.10.0/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.java#L3487) for the deprecated function is:

```java
    @Deprecated
    public static void writeStringToFile(final File file, final String data) throws IOException {
        writeStringToFile(file, data, Charset.defaultCharset(), false);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

[Have a look](https://similarapi.appspot.com/api/org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile)
From your question I think you are searching option for `FileUtils.writeStringToFile`.
This link will provide the same.